# Need help to assign category, order and pagination to a new php code

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, categories

I am using a WordPress plugin called “Favorites”. The plugin "favorites/bookmarks" the posts for the user. But the problem is that it displays the bookmarked posts according to the date the post was created, not by the date and time user has bookmarked it.
**Currently I am using this code:**

```
<?php 
  $favorites = get_user_favorites();
  $x = 1;
?>
<?php   
  if ($favorites) : $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
  $favorites_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category' => 9, // 9 is ID for English category
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post__in' => $favorites,
    'paged' => $paged 
  ));

  echo "<ol class='favorite-list-ol'>";
?>
<?php
  if ($favorites_query->have_posts()) : while ( $favorites_query->have_posts() ) : $favorites_query->the_post();
?>

<li class="favorite-list-li">
  <?php echo get_the_title($favorite); ?> 
</li>

<?php
  endwhile;
  $x++;
  echo "</ol>"; 
?>
```

I found code, which does what I want i.e. displays the posts according to the date and time user has bookmarked it..
But this code does not catch WordPress's category, pagination, or order.
**New Code is:**

```
$filters = array(
  'post_type' => array(
    'post'`enter code here`
  ),
  'status' => array(
    'publish'
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => array(
    5
  ),
  'order' => array(
     'DESC'
  ),
  'terms' => array(
    'category' => array(
      'english'
    ),
  'paged' => array(
    $paged
  ),
   )
);
the_user_favorites_list($user_id = null, $site_id = null, $include_links = true, $filters = $filters);
```

Comment: Please indicate what your code does, and how that differs from what you expect it to do.

Comment: spelling, grammar, remove Please/help cruft as per SO guidelines

Comment: @SherylHohman I have refined the question now. please review it

Comment: You will probably need to edit code within the `the_user_favorites_list()` and/or `get_user_favorites()` functions, so that they store/retrieve more info that ithey currently do.  WordPress specific questions might better be suited to SO's sister [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) site that is dedicated to WordPress, since the answer to this question, even the question itself is dependent on knowledge specific to the WordPress ecosystem. Either way, I suspect we would need to see the contents of the functions mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow/help/how-to-ask), including the link on "minimal reproduceable examples". Take note that grammar, spelling, etc are *important*, plus it shows attention to detail (important in programming), that you put time into crafting your question, and signals respect to volunteers' time, not to mention that it makes text easier to read/comprehend, and keeps SO quality high. Cheers, I hope you find your answer.